# Counting change operations c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have an aplication which performs some basic morphological analysis, and I am looking for an efficient means to count the number of change operations needed to transform a word into another, character by character changes.

Thanks in advance people.

Comment: What type of "change" operations are you allowed to do?  Can we add/remove/alter letters in any position or do we have any special conditions on how changes must occur?

Comment: It is unrestricted in terms of conditions, so no worries on method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That sounds a lot like the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

> The Levenshtein distance between two
>   strings is defined as the minimum
>   number of edits needed to transform
>   one string into the other, with the
>   allowable edit operations being
>   insertion, deletion, or substitution
>   of a single character

The article links to other comparison algorithms as well.